# ActionBar with tabs, crash when I push tab with WebView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have created the tabs in the MainActivity. The tabs are declared correctly, and they loaded perfectly.  Following these tabs, the program stops. The WebView is declared in fragment1.xml

```
public class FragmentsTab1 extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;
    WebView navegador1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from fragment1.xml
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);

        try{
            navegador1 = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webkit1);
            WebSettings webSettings = navegador1.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
            navegador1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            navegador1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                return false;
            }
        });        

    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mFragment = new FragmentsTab1();
        // Attach fragment1.xml layout
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
        ft.attach(mFragment);


    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Remove fragment1.xml layout
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**LOGCAT ERRORS :**

```
06-23 06:59:50.156: W/System.err(1917): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 06:59:50.156: W/System.err(1917):     at com.example.prueba.FragmentsTab1.onCreate(FragmentsTab1.java:24)
06-23 06:59:50.166: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1673)
06-23 06:59:50.166: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:854)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 06:59:50.176: W/System.err(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/System.err(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/System.err(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/System.err(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/System.err(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/System.err(1917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 06:59:50.186: D/AndroidRuntime(1917): Shutting down VM
06-23 06:59:50.186: W/dalvikvm(1917): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2f5b648)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.example.prueba.FragmentsTab1.onCreate(FragmentsTab1.java:33)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1673)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:854)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-23 06:59:50.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is this ( " `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);` " ) ? please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I add the logcat, but I can't copy&paste to see it properly.